# Javascript cannot read property of undefined but alert can show the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am making a react form application. Using control hook to obtain the data from the forms along with states. I have an about page where state is initialised by

```
const [formAboutYouData, setFormAboutYouData] = React.useState(undefined);
```

and onSubmit i call a submission function which uses it to make the axios post API call. *formAboutYouData* has an atribute called *firstName* which it has obtained from the forms(name of the input box). Inside submission function i can print it by using console or alert(formAboutYouData.firstName) it works fine. Now problem is in axios call if i use like

> ```
> axios
>   .post(
>     "URL",
>     { firstName: formAboutYouData.firstName },
>     {
>       headers: submissionRequestHeader,
>     }
>   )
> ```

it works fine instead if i use

> ```
> axios
>   .post(
>     "URL",
>     ,submissionBody
>     {
>       headers: submissionRequestHeader,
>     }
>   )
> ```

and declare submission body separately as

> const submissionBody={
> firstName: formAboutYouData.firstName,
> }

then i am getting error as cannot read property firstName of undefined.
Why is it happening ?

Comment: Have you tried chaning the default value of `formAboutYouData` to include the field firstName? even if empty? I assume it's the issue of asyncrhonously updating the value with setFormAboutYouData

Comment: use a check before reading  const submissionBody= formAboutYouData ? { firstName: formAboutYouData.firstName } :'' . Also, .post(
    "URL",
    submissionBody,
    -> fix the comma after submissionBody

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski problem is adding fields won't scale right if I had to include more fields in the future

Comment: I assume that your submissionBody has only firstname and it is not empty. So pls try this **axios.post("URL",{ submissionBody.firstName},{
      headers: submissionRequestHeader,
    })**. Also, you got an extra Comma after url.